# ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c

Let me start by saying, I'm not really a beginner at all this, but by no means an expert. I have Oracle 12c enterprise set up on a Oracle Enterprise Linux ver 7 box.
This has always worked fine, start Linux, from a terminal window:

```
[oracle@oradev ~]$ sqlplus /nolog
SQL> conn SYS as SYSDBA
Enter password: xxxxx`
SQL> startup
[oracle@oradev ~]$lsnrctl start
```

All was well. I have this running on VMware® Workstation 12 Pro, 12.5.0 build-4352439. I recently updated VMware...now when I get to
startup  I get:

```
SQL> startup
ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
ORA-00130: invalid listener address '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oradev.attlocal.net)(PORT=1522))'
SQL>
```

Please advise?

Comment: Please post the contents of listener.ora file. Is your host name same as before the update?

Comment: I kinda thought that was the issue...the host name is changed, either on the box , in VMWare...or the listener.ora (I couldn't remember that file name..or should i say the listener is not matching the host.

Comment: SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
   (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
   (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1)
   (SID_NAME = orcl)
  )
 )
LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oradev.attlocal.net)(PORT = 1522))
  )
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
  )
 )

Comment: Sorry...using this form posting is not user friendly...to me anyway. so, how do I check to see if the host name on the box matches listener.ora.  I have to assume nothing changed listenr.ora, and somehow the box got renamed, or VM is renamed.

Comment: [oracle@oradev ~]$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: oradev
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: b78abe195ee04136a8e0d9b6fe0a0467
           Boot ID: 66dac5186f3c48c48985fd2de64dd6da
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.2
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:2:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.8.13-118.11.2.el7uek.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
[oracle@oradev ~]$

Comment: Please edit the question to add new information, and format it so it's readable. Has the Linux domain name changed - what, if anything, does `oradev.attlocal.net` resolve to?

Comment: http://www.aanning.com/ajissues/oracle_startup/notes.txt

Comment: Hi, I'm unable to format or enter my text in a user friendly fashion....I must not be seeing something...its very cumbersome to use this forum.  I posted every thing in more readable in my link above.  No oracle settings have changed, not by me, I have only regularly done yum-update and most recently the VMware update.   how do I "resolve to" the oradev.attlocal.net?

Comment: Adding tnsping results: (all this and more can be seen at the below link)

http://www.aanning.com/ajissues/orac...rtup/notes.txt

 4 pings and results are at above web link


 tnsping oradev.attlocal.net

 tnsping oradev.attlocal.net:1522

 tnsping www.aanning.com

 tnsping www.aanning.com:1522

Comment: Show the contents of ` $ cat /etc/hosts`. Also ask moderators to migrate this question to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your host name is correct in the value of the `local_listener` parameter.

My hostname is as follows:

[oracle@ora12c admin]$ hostname
ora12c.dba.com

Go to `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/` directory.

Then create TNS entry in the `tnsnames.ora` file as shown below to point the listener(In my case its `LISTNER_ORACDB`).

```
[oracle@ora12c admin]$ vi tnsnames.ora 
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORACDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora12c.dba.com)(PORT = 1522)) 


ORACDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora12c.dba.com)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracdb)
    )
  )
```

Next,

```
[oracle@ora12c admin]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> alter system set local_listener='LISTENER_ORACDB';
```

Comment: These have not changed:

Comment: # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oradev.attlocal.net)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.attlocal.net)
    )
  )

Comment: SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
   (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
   (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1)
   (SID_NAME = orcl)
  )
 )
LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oradev.attlocal.net)(PORT = 1522))
  )
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
  )
 )